# print checked checkbox value from FORM in php?

Tags: php

I have a simple form in my html page:

```
<html>
<head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method='post' name='template' action="echo.php">
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName' value='1234'>1234<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName' value='5847'>5847<br>
      <br>
      <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
    </form>
</body>
```

Once the user hits Submit I want the page to print all the checked colors like this:

```
1234
5847
```

What's a good way of doing this in PHP?

Thank you

Comment: Use brackets in the 'name' attribute of the checkbox input: checkboxName[ ]. Doing this checked values will be put in an array that you will be able to read in PHP using the below code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Give array element to name.

```
<html>
<head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method='post' name='template' action="echo.php">
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='red'>Red<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='green'>Green<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='blue'>Blue<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='yellow'>Yellow<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='purple'>Purple<br>
      <br>
      <input type='submit' value='GO'>
    </form>
</body>
```

And then show it like this:

```
is_array($_POST['checkboxName']){    
foreach($_POST['checkboxName'] as $value)
    {
        echo 'Checked: '.$value ;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I did exactly how you said here, but I get this: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/echo.php on line 2.   Where line 2 is this:  foreach($_POST['checkboxName'] as $value)   Any idea?

Comment: Your foreach loop is in echo.php file ??

Comment: this is my whole echo.php file:  <?php
  foreach($_POST['checkboxName'] as $value)
  {
      echo $value.'<br/>';
  }
?>

Comment: Pl make sure your form code should same as I write in answer. And then try var_dump($_POST['checkboxName']) in top of echo.php file.

Comment: Ok, I did that. I only put the var_dump($_POST['checkboxName']); in the echo.php and if I select red, green and blue and hit GO I get this: string(4) "blue"

Comment: It means you don't generate array my friend. Set name='checkboxName[]' as name in all checkboxes and then try....

Comment: with the echo.php file looking like this:  
<?php
var_dump($_POST['checkboxName']);


if(is_array($_POST['checkboxName'])){    
foreach($_POST['checkboxName'] as $value)
    {
        echo 'Checked: '.$value ;
    }
}

?>
 I still only see:  string(4) "blue"

Comment: Remove this now:  var_dump($_POST['checkboxName']); from echo.php file. And Set all check boxes like this: <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='red'>Red<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='green'>Green<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='blue'>Blue<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='yellow'>Yellow<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='purple'>Purple<br>

Comment: I did that and with the echo.php like this: 
<?php
if(is_array($_POST['checkboxName'])){    
  foreach($_POST['checkboxName'] as $value)
    {
        echo 'Checked: '.$value ;
    }
}
?> I now see nothing.

Comment: ok, I found the issue. My HMTL page containing the form missed the closing tag </html>. Now it works. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

in your form page change name field checkboxName into checkboxName[]

```
<html>
<head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method='post' name='template' action="echo.php">
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='red'>Red<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='green'>Green<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='blue'>Blue<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='yellow'>Yellow<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='purple'>Purple<br>
      <br>
      <input type='submit' value='GO' >
    </form>
</body>
```

in your echo.php page

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST['checkboxName'] as $value)
    {
      echo $value.'<br>';
    }
?>
```

If you check all the checkboxes, this script will output:

```
red
green
blue
yellow
purple
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_POST['checkboxName'] as $value)
{
    echo 'Checked: '.$value.'
';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change the textbox names as an array like,

```
  <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='red'>Red<br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='green'>Green<br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='blue'>Blue<br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='yellow'>Yellow<br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='purple'>Purple<br>
```

Then add  php code like

```
 foreach($_POST['checkboxName'] as $value)
 {
    echo $value.'<br/>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the color to the name field with `checkboxName` as first word and remove all the value fields.

```
<html>
<head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method='post' name='template' action="echo.php">
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxNamered'>Red<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxNamegreen'>Green<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxNameblue'>Blue<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxNameyellow'>Yellow<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxNamepurple'>Purple<br>
      <br>
      <input type='submit' name='submit' value='GO'>
    </form>
</body>
```

If there are multiple fields with the same name, then only one field with value can be accessed by **PHP**, so you should make each name fields unique. Hence I made each item like this :

> checkboxNamered, checkboxNamegreen, checkboxNameblue etc...

In PHP, we check if the first 12 characters are `checkBoxName`, if it is, we strip out `checkBoxName` from the name field and echo out the remaining part :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
  $firstChar=substr($k, 0, 12);
  if($firstChar=="checkboxName"){
   echo str_replace("checkboxName", "", $k);
  }
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can use array easily more than this way!

Answer (score 0):

Change the textbox names as an array like

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='1234'>1234<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkboxName[]' value='5847'>5847<br>
```

Then add php code like

```
foreach($_POST['checkboxName'] as $value)
{
    echo "Checked values: ".$value;
}
```

Explanation: the input field text name make as an array ex: checkboxName[]. You can use any name but remember put [] in after that name, and rest of the other checkbox need to be with this name! And after catch that array version data in php codes.

PHP foreach loop go through this array and $value variable is contains value/s what we choose using checkbox.